# Texture flipping behaviour

Tags: opengl, textures, projection-matrix

I was having this problem with OpenGL where I'd have all my textures being rendered upside down. I did the most logical thing I could think of and tried reversing the order of the mapping and that fixed the issue. But why? I know that OpenGL's coordinate system is cartesian and that it works by mapping each uv to a specific vertex. I had something like [0,0], [0,1], [1,1], [1,0] which would theoretically as far as I understand it go from:

top-left -> bottom-left -> bottom-right -> top-right.

I changed this to: [1,1], [1,0], [0,0], [0,1] which would represent:

bottom-right -> top-right -> top-left -> bottom left.

In my understanding it should be quite the opposite. Making a pretty quick sketch on paper it shows me that the initial order would theoretically render my texture correctly and not upside down. Am I correct and theres something else messing with my rendering? Like my perspective matrix?

This is my orthographic matrix:

```
    Matrix4f ortho = new Matrix4f();
    ortho.setIdentity();

    float zNear = 0.01f;
    float zFar = 100f;

    ortho.m00 = 2 / (float) RenderManager.getWindowWidth();
    ortho.m11 = 2 / -(float) RenderManager.getWindowHeight();
    ortho.m22 = -2 / (zFar - zNear);

    return ortho;
```

I can't really say I understand it though, I had quite a hard time with it. And looking through youtube tutorials and articles you can see most people don't really understand it either, they just use it. I do have a good linear algebra background but still can't wrap my head around how is this matrix normalizing my coordinates (screen coords to OpenGL coords (-1,1)). Anyway, I digress, any help is appreciated.

Comment: In normalized device space, the bottom left is at (-1, -1) and the top right is (1, 1)

Comment: well, you have two coordinate spaces to work here: the space where your vertices are defined in (and that is defined by both GLs conventions, as well as the transformations you apply, e.g. your ortho matrix). And the texture space. And in texture space, the originin is simply where the first pixel you feed into `glTexImage*()` will end up.